# squid proxy - use ipv6 only for outgoing traffic

Tags: proxy, ipv6, squid, ipv4

I want to set up a squid proxy to use ipv6 only for outgoing traffic.
I want the ip4 address to be totally invisible to the service I connecting to.
I don't care about fallback and lack of ipv6 support, the service I connecting to, fully support ipv6 only.
With my setup, the IPv4 and internal IP is visible. What I missing?

Thanks

Heres my squid.conf:

```
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access allow localhost
http_port 3128
http_port 3129
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

http_access allow all
acl to_ipv4 dst ipv4
http_access deny to_ipv4

acl user1 myportname 3128
acl user2 myportname 3129

tcp_outgoing_address x:x:x:x::1 user1
tcp_outgoing_address x:x:x:x::2 user2

forwarded_for delete
via off
follow_x_forwarded_for deny all
request_header_access X-Forwarded-For deny all
request_header_access From deny all
request_header_access Referer deny all
request_header_access User-Agent deny all
request_header_access Authorization allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all
request_header_access Content-Length allow all
request_header_access Content-Type allow all
request_header_access Date allow all
request_header_access Host allow all
request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all
request_header_access Pragma allow all
request_header_access Accept allow all
request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all
request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Accept-Language allow all
request_header_access Connection allow all
request_header_access All deny all
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the following config file on on Squid version 4.14 running on  Windows 11 which worked to only allow IPv6 traffic:

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16
acl localnet src fc00::/7
acl localnet src fe80::/10
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80
acl Safe_ports port 21
acl Safe_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 70
acl Safe_ports port 210
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535
acl Safe_ports port 280
acl Safe_ports port 488
acl Safe_ports port 591
acl Safe_ports port 777
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl ipv4_from src ipv4
acl ipv4_to dst ipv4
dns_v4_first off
acl to_ipv6 dst ipv6
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access deny ipv4_to
http_access deny ipv4_from
http_access deny !to_ipv6
http_access allow to_ipv6
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
http_port 3128
coredump_dir /var/cache/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0% 0
refresh_pattern . 0 20% 4320
dns_nameservers 2620:fe::fe
max_filedescriptors 3200
```

I confirmed it on https://ipv6-test.com/ and found correctly no ip4 connectivity but fully working ipv6 connectivity.

They key sections are the deny at *http_access* level on **ipv4_to** , **ipv4_from** and the reverse rule **!to_ipv6**

Note: The DNS server is also setup to use IPv6 server.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and this resolved it for me:

Add this to your squid.conf file:

```
forwarded_for off
```

This will exclude the forwarding of the system's (ipv4) IP address.